# Add Hover display for table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I have a table, but it is not in a list format, meaning not a column/row format. I look for specific cells to add a hover event that displays a description of the cell.

```
$("#TableID td").hover(function(){
//ifCellThatIWant
   $(this).append("<span>Message that was brought in</span>");
   },
   function(){
    $(this).children().remove();
    });
```

The problem is right now is that the hover displays a span(with info. inside) that I used jquery to append the span to the cell when mouseover, which expands the cell, which is an effect that I don't like or want. I'm Trying to have an out of the table look,but still be by the cell that triggered the event; because if the span has a lot of info. in it, expanding the cell dynamically will start to look pretty nasty.  Also will help if I had some type of css direction on how will I make the display for the mouseover "description" span look nice. My mind thought is that a way to accomplish what I want is giver the appended span the position of my mouse cursor when hover, but not sure if its the right approach or what the syntax would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the span display as block and set the z-index greater than anything else on the page.  Then you can absolute position it and set the left and top properties to the x and y positions of the mouse location.

EDIT:

Here's a demo of what I mean --> http://jsbin.com/odape.  Instead of appending a span, I would suggest just creating a placeholder one at the bottom of your html to use for each cell and just change the text to display (not sure how you were bringing it in so I didn't add it in my example.

Comment: so from your comments my css should look like: css{display:block, z-index: 10, top: e.PageY, left: e.PageX, position: absolute;}

Comment: That works perfectly, but I was also trying to get a nice display for the span with css oppose to just words, I had just a yellow background, would you know what that css, for example the one that you usualy see for a information display..like the cartoon talking with the "cloud" above in comic strips

Comment: A cartoon talking with a cloud is probably going to require wrapping a div around the span and floating an image around the text in the span.  I don't have any exact examples of that.  But personally, I would just add padding and a border and background color to the span to make it look a little nicer.